# Returning the numbers in a string as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to return the numerical part of a string. I've looked through Stackoverflow but so far the code doesn't work for me - I think there's a simple function I could use here.

I want to return the numerical values in a string, and have them put into a specific cell.

I've tried `Val` which doesn't work as the string is something like `"This is 2"` and therefore it just returns a 0. I would want to return the value 2 into a specific cell.

```vb
Dim mytext As String
mytext = c  'where c is my string

Dim myChars() As char
myChars() = mytext.ToCharArray()

' Loop through the array testing if each is a digit
Dim ch As characters

For Each ch In myChars
     If char.IsDigit(ch) Then
          cell.Value = ch
     End If
Next
```

This gives me a compile error - user-defined type not defined...

The code I've looked at doesn't seem to make sense - I know it should be pretty simple but I'm not sure I understand what is wrong!

Comment: Given `"This is 2 and this is 3"`, is the result `2`, `3` or `23`?

Comment: @GSerg , I would be looking for 23 - I have updated the code to show another attempt...

Comment: The code did not work for you because you took VB.NET code. Please see the VBA code in the duplicate question.

Comment: @GSerg apologies! I didn't know this question already existed. Many thanks :)